# Number of projective subspaces of dimension $k$ of projective space of a vector space over a finite field of order $q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of $q$ elements. How many projective subspaces of dimension $k$ are there in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, the projective space of $V$

Comment: Can you do it for $k=1$? Try something..

Comment: Can you say how many linear subspaces $V$ has? How about how many affine subspaces?

Comment: Yes that would be $\binom n k_q$ and $q^{n-k}\binom n k_q$